# Keeping partial production data for develpoment in Django

Tags: django

A django app I am working on helps write reports. The report templates as well as report text template fragments are kept in a database. What is the best practice in Django to have only these two models - report templates and fragment templates exported and then loaded in dev environments.

One option is to [use dumpdata and loaddata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596610/pull-data-from-production-to-dev-for-debugging-django), but that appears to do it for everything and that's undesirable.

Any ideas/hints/tips appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried passing options to dumpdata such as: dumpdata <appname appname appname.Model ...>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just dump the data for a specific model using the `dumpdata` optional arguments

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model

`python manage.py dumpdata yourapp.YourModel` will output only the data for the specific model.

I like to mirror production environment when developing.  This can be accomplished extremely easily by just exporting your database to a .sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Another option will be available in Django 1.6, [according to this ticket.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16330) Once that has landed, you'll be able to select the pks that you wish to dump from a given table using the `--pks` argument of dumpdata.

If you wish to start using it before 1.6 is released, you can do so, just grab the file [from here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/59235816bd063cb8b24acfc92ae1b5cd09a1f7ba/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py).